# Copy/Paste variable-defined range between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, Raw Data and a user-created `varSheetName`.

I dump a huge data extract into Raw Data, and extract columns (based on the header field, which I can find no problem) to the new sheet. The column number the header is found on is always going to be different, as will be the number of rows below it.
EX: I find the header "models/0/availability", on column ?, with ?? rows to copy to `varSheetName`.

Knowing the copy & paste column #, and the last row #, I run this code:

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(varSheetName)
    .Range(.Cells(intPasteRow, intPasteCol), .Cells(intLastRow, intPasteCol)).Value = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(.Cells(1, iCopyCol), .Cells(intLastRow, iCopyCol)).Value
End With
```

I get

> Runtime 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy a Range by Assignment

- When you copy in this way you need to make sure that the number of rows and number of columns of both ranges is equal:

  ```
  intLastRow - IntPasteRow <> intLastRow - 1 ' unless IntPasteRow = 1
  ```
- To avoid those long unreadable lines, use variables. That's what they're for.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(1, iCopyCol), _
        sws.Cells(intLastRow, iCopyCol))
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(varSheetName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Cells(intPasteRow, intPasteCol)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
    ' Copy.
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - I see the wisdom in this approach.  One problem though - Excel is giving me "Invalid or Unqualified Reference" at sws.Range(.Cells  Specifically .cells.  Any thoughts there?

Comment: That's because my initial answer contained a With statement. Fixed it. Just added `sws` in front of the dots. Those cells and this range all 'belong' to `sws`.

Comment: I'll cop to not totally following the purpose of `dfCell`, but running into issues still, I retooled the destination code as follows:

`Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Worksheets(varSheetName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dws.Cells(1, intPasteCol), dws.Cells(intLastRow, intPasteCol))`

This gets me across the finish line - I can now feed the ranges the targeting columns & rows in a loop I can easily adjust and expand as needed.  Many thanks!